# How can I change HDFS replication factor for my Spark program?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I need to change the HDFS replication factor from 3 to 1 for my Spark program. While searching, I came up with the "spark.hadoop.dfs.replication" property, but by looking at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html, it doesn't seem to exist anymore. So, how can I change the hdfs replication factor from my Spark program or using spark-submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDFDS configuration is not specific in any way to Spark. You should be able to modify it, using standard Hadoop configuration files. In particular `hdfs-site.xml`:

```
<property> 
  <name>dfs.replication<name> 
  <value>3<value> 
<property>
```

It is also possible to access Hadoop configuration using `SparkContext` instance:

```
val hconf: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
hconf.setInt("dfs.replication", 3)
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use `spark.hadoop.dfs.replication` to set the replication factor in HDFS in your spark application. But why you cannot find it in the https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html? That's because that link **ONLY** contains spark specific configuration. As a matter of fact, any property you set started with `spark.hadoop.*` will be automatically translated to a Hadoop property, stripping the beginning "`spark.haddoop.`". You can find how it is implemented at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d7b1fcf8f0a267322af0592b2cb31f1c8970fb16/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkHadoopUtil.scala

The method you should look for is `appendSparkHadoopConfigs`

Comment: For testing in the shell, I had to pass it as a command-line argument: `spark-shell --conf spark.hadoop.dfs.replication=1`.  (If I didn't do that, trying to change/set the value inside the shell didn't work.  I mean... the value would change (i.e., "get" would show the new value of "1"), but files were still written with the default replication of 3.)