# hadoop fs -du output does not reflect replication factor

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

As discussed in several other questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393558/size-of-hdfs-filesystem-using-du-command) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377747/how-to-understand-hdfs-du-results)), the `hadoop fs -du -s -h` command (or equivalently `hdfs dfs -s -h`) shows two values:

1. The pure file size
2. The file size taking into account replication

e.g.

```
19.9 M  59.6 M  /path/folder/test.avro
```

So normally we'd expect the second number to be 3x the first number, on our cluster with replication factor 3.

But when checking up on a running Spark job recently, the first number was 246.9 K, and the second was 3.4 G - approximately 14,000 times larger!

Does this indicate a problem? Why isn't the replicated size 3x the raw size?

Is this because one of the values takes into account block size, and the other doesn't, perhaps?

The Hadoop [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#du) on this command isn't terribly helpful, stating only:

> The du returns three columns with the following format
>
> `size disk_space_consumed_with_all_replicas full_path_name`

Comment: 248K or 248MB?  3.4GB is 14000x 248K.  Also, you can change replication factor for your spark app (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098118/how-can-i-change-hdfs-replication-factor-for-my-spark-program).

Comment: Thanks, now fixed. Just to confirm that the replication factor is currently 3.